# Sending email from Android app

Tags: java, android, email, jakarta-mail, sender

I am trying to a develop an android app that sends email using JavaMail. I have tried the code bellow as console application and it works, but when I use in as an android app from the emulator it throws exception with no message.  I have modified the manifest.xml and put

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

but it still doesn’t work. The exception is thrown at `message.setText("Welcome to JavaMail");`  So please help me out!

I am using the `mail.jar` and `activation.jar` from Sun.

Bellow is the full code on the ClickHandler.

```
 public void btnSendClickHandler(View view)
   {
    try{

        String host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        String from = "Username@gmail.com";
        String pass = "Password";
        Properties props = System.getProperties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true"); // added this line
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
        props.put("mail.smtp.user", from);
        props.put("mail.smtp.password", pass);
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

        String[] to = {"toEmailAddress@gmail.com"}; // added this line

        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);

        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

        InternetAddress[] toAddress = new InternetAddress[to.length];

        // To get the array of addresses
        for( int i=0; i < to.length; i++ ) { 
            toAddress[i] = new InternetAddress(to[i]);
        }


        for( int i=0; i < toAddress.length; i++) {
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddress[i]);
        }

        message.setSubject("sending in a group");
        message.setText("Welcome to JavaMail");//The exception is thrown here   

        Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
        transport.connect(host, from, pass);
        transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
        transport.close();
 } catch(Exception e){Toast.makeText(this, e.toString(),
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                      }}
```

Comment: What exception do you get? Can you post your stacktrace here?

Comment: Just curious, why can't you send emails via the intent mechanism and exploit whatever email client the user has?

Comment: there is an easiest way to send email using default email functionality, then why you are trying to use these jars. Is there any other reason? http://www.anddev.org/email_send_intent_intentchooser-t3295.html

Comment: Check this article, is very useful: http://www.jondev.net/articles/Sending_Emails_without_User_Intervention_%28no_Intents%29_in_Android

I think you are missing some SocketFactory property in your code, for instance:

`props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.SocketFactory");`

Also, I've used activation.jar, additionnal.jar and mail.jar from http://code.google.com/p/javamail-android/downloads/list


I hope this hints can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the exception could be solved if you set the body using something like this:

`_multipart = new MimeMultipart();`

`BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();`

`messageBodyPart.setText("Welcome to JavaMail");`

`_multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);`

`message.setContent(_multipart);`

Comment: I have found out that the problem is more than it seems. JavaMial doesn't work well on Android, but luckly I have found a website discussion that has fixed this problem ( www.jondev.net/articles/Sending_Emails_without_User_Intervention_(no_Intents)_in_­Android ). If you read the comments and do as the post, it will work. And @ASMaitre(I did that before and had the same outcome).